# how to customize the page setup in javascript print

Tags: javascript, printing

i want to print a page through javascript function window.print(). i am using 62mm wide paper roll for this . but when i print it takes length of a4 paper size. how i reduce the length of paper in javascript.
i used the css for this but didn't work.
the css i used for this is as follow:

```
@media print {
  body { 
    color : #000000; 
    background : #ffffff; 
    font-family : "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size : 12pt; 
    width: 2.4409449in /*width of index card*/
    height:2.4409449in /*height of index card*/
  }
}
```

please help me thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size of the paper. It affects to the printer configuration and you don't have access to it through javascript. *The user* has to change it manually before printing. The only you can do, as you did, is to set a width/height.

Comment: Well, as idea, you can notice the user about it. Like "please, remember to change paper size configuration before printing"

Comment: [kmsdev](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3648578/kmsdev) sir but in my application multiple print option & all are in different length .so it's irritative task to change printer setting every time.

Comment: The problem here is that if you need to use measures greater than A4 you have to notice users, rest of cases isn't necessary. Maybe you should to think if you need other technology like java to do it

Answer (score -1):

I had been this same problem. I solved this by using jsPrintSetup Addon with firefox. By installing this addon we can dynamically control several print settings of firefox like page height, width, header, footer, margin etc